# JQuery ZURB Reveal Plugin - stop video on any close method

Tags: jquery

I am using the JQuery Reveal plugin with nice success to show HTML5 video with a simple Flash fallback. Reveal is working great on IE8, IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Win XP, Win 7, OS X, iPad 2, and Android 2.3.

It is only being used to show video and also works fine when showing many videos on one page.

I have a "close" link in the modal window that works as does the Esc key and clicking the background. However . . . I have only been able to find how to pause the closed video for the close link by adding the following script in the HTML page

```
$('.close-reveal-modal').click(function() {
    $('video, audio').each(function() {
        $(this)[0].pause();    
    });
});
```

How do I add code to make it also pause the video for the Esc key and the background click?

Pausing the video stops it from continuing to play when the modal window is dismissed and that's what I need to do.

Clearly I am not even a n00b in JavaScript because I look at the associated jquery.reveal.js file and see all the closing events but have no clue how to add it in (lol, lots of poking at it with either breaking it fully or not affecting any changes!).

Thanks!

http://subquark.com/html5/lightbox/course.htm current testing sample

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue and figured out where to edit the source. In the file `jquery.reveal.js`, lines 95-124:

```
  modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
    if(!locked) {
        lockModal();
        if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
            modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
            modal.animate({
                "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                "opacity" : 0
            }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                unlockModal();
            });                 
        }   
        if(options.animation == "fade") {
            modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
            modal.animate({
                "opacity" : 0
            }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                unlockModal();
            });                 
        }   
        if(options.animation == "none") {
            modal.css({'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
            modalBG.css({'display' : 'none'});  
        }       
    }
    //ADD YOUR EXTRA EVENTS HERE!
    modal.unbind('reveal:close');
  });
```

Add your extra code where I marked (at the end).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed something similar for a site that was using a YouTube iframe to show video in a lightbox.  I changed the code from this:

```
  modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
    if(!locked) {
        lockModal();
        if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
```

to this:

```
  modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
    if(!locked) {
        lockModal();
        modal.children('iframe').remove(); // Remove iframes.
        if(options.animation == "fadeAndPop") {
```

This solves the problem I ran into of the iframe still being visible in Chrome, and stops playing video.

Comment: thanks Jesse! that was the spot!

and thanks John, your technique works as well =)

Comment: Hi, the problem I am experiencing with this, is that when you try to run the video again after closing it, the modal will drop down, but there is no video in the modal. You have to refresh the page for the modal and video to work as intended.